# Logging In Firebase via Phone Number Workaround

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I've thought of a workaround in firebase(its actually very simple) to log in via phone number instead of email. That is when logging in the Phone Number is associated with the email and the listener gets the email under that number and that email will be signed in via `SignInWithEmaiLAndPassword` however, it doesn't seem to go to the last barrier. Which is, I'll show my code first. Here's my code snippet:

**Listeners to get the Values and SignInWithEmail Part**

```
//ONCLICK LISTENER
loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
        //Perform Login Operation
        userEmailString = userEmailEdit.getText().toString().trim();
        userPasswordString = userPasswordEdit.getText().toString().trim();

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(userEmailString) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(userPasswordString) && userPasswordString != null && userEmailString != null) {
            /*UPDATE*/

            final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            String location = "Users/" + userEmailString;
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, location, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference(location);
            ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1) {
                    if (dataSnapshot1 != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "NOT NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        //dataSnapshot points to the User node with list of users
                        //Retrieve data from the childrens emailUser,passWordUser,userID and Invoke start activity
                        for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot1.getChildren()) {

                            final String userEmail = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("USER_EMAIL").getValue());
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, userEmail, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPasswordString).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful())
                                    {
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Task Succesful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                checkUserValidation(dataSnapshot, userEmail);
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }else
                                    {
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "User Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                                /*Added*/
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
            /*/UPDATE*/
        }
    }
});
```

**Validation Part**

```
private void checkUserValidation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String emailForVer) {
    Iterator iterator  = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Made it to validation", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    

    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
        DataSnapshot dataUser  = (DataSnapshot) iterator.next();
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Now on Snapshot", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         if(String.valueOf(dataUser.child("emailUser").getValue()).equals(emailForVer) && String.valueOf(dataUser.child("userPhone").getValue()).equals(emailForVer) && dataUser.child("emailUser") != null && dataUser.child("userName") !=null) {
             Intent accountActivity = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Welcome.class);
                 Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Made it to final", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 String user = String.valueOf(dataUser.child("userName"));
                accountActivity.putExtra("USER_NAME", user);
                startActivity(accountActivity);
                finish();
        }
    }
}
```

The last barrier is the last `Toast` I wanted to show, the one where its saying "MADE IT TO FINAL" can I have your opinion on why I cant get through this? Thank you very much.

Also dont recommend me to the phone authentication of firebase, I already know that, so this is really just a workaround, because I don't have time anymore.(Last minute changes that the makes you cry) well, my Firebase structure is cool, and I'm able to fetch what I want. Except that I just cant get through the last toast. Please help.